# Consume C#.NET COM Component in C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com

I noticed that someone asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648103/using-com-object-in-c) on **how to consume C# COM component in C++**

But that thread is marked as duplicate because the title of question is too generic and does not specify C#.

Since I am not able to answer that question, I am creating this new question which I'll answer and others can also put forward there suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1482131/50447

Comment: That thread(which Rowland Shaw thinks is duplicate) is about calling C# COM component from another C# COM component to test whether its a valid COM component or not. My thread is about consuming C#.NET COM component from C++ code.

Comment: In which case it's exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648103/using-com-object-in-c?

Comment: yes Rowland Shaw you are correct now, and i have already mentioned the same URL as an HREF for "Similar Question" in the description of my question. And why I replied here is because there was no editable box to put the answer there. This also i mentioned in my original question.

Comment: When something is closed as a duplicate, you can add your answer to the original question, in this case, over at http://stackoverflow.com/q/410005/50447

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer of this situation from my side:

Referring a C++ COM component is easy in .NET; all we have to do is to

- register (regsvr32 )
- Add a reference to the COM dll in the Visual Studio Solution
- An Interop file will be created in the bin directory of .NET project and we are done

**But the reverse is not as simple as above.**
So this time I have come up with Steps we need to follow in order to refer a COM visible .NET dll in C++ code.

- Register the COM Visible .NET assambly with regasm like this:
  regasm <dll_name_with_full_path> /tlb
  e.g.

  ```
  regasm "C:\SampleProject\bin\Release\Atreya.Anugrah.ComVisibleComponent.dll" /tlb
  ```
- Refer .NET component in .h file like this:
  #import "<generated_tlb_name_with_full_path>" named_guids raw_interfaces_only 
  e.g.

  ```
  #import "C:\SampleProject\bin\Release\Atreya.Anugrah.ComVisibleComponent.tlb"  named_guids raw_interfaces_only
  ```
- Create a class in .h file, and declare member variable like this:
  ComVisibleComponent::* memberVariablePointer; 
  e.g.

  ```
  Atreya_Anugrah_ComVisibleComponent::IMyInterface* m_pIMyInterface;
  ```
- Now, Initialize the declared member variable pointer in .cpp file like this:

  ```
  hr = CoCreateInstance( 
  __uuidof(Atreya_Anugrah_ComVisibleComponent::<Name_of_CoClass_Implementing_Interface>), // COM class id 
  NULL, // Outer unknown
  CLSCTX_ALL, // Server INFO 
  Atreya_Anugrah_ComVisibleComponent::IID_<Name_of_Interface>, // interface id
  (void**) &m_pIMyInterface);  // Returned Interface                                                                                                                   

  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
  _com_error e(hr);
  strErrorMsg.Format("Error: Unable to create COM Visible .NET component. hr = %d. Message = %s",hr, e.ErrorMessage());
  return hr;
  }

  //you are good to use your initialized pointer here :)   
  m_pIMyInterface->foo()
  ```

P.S. This post does not explain that how can we make our .NET component as COM visible. Please refer other post/article for that as it is quite simple activity.

Namaste! (Greetings)
Anugrah Atreya

Comment: I agree this is duplicate, Admin can delete if possible.